# @Html.DisplayNameFor and Single page application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

The `DisplayName` attribute is very useful. It will affected all the places using `@Html.DisplayNameFor()` in the view. Is there anyway to use the attribute in Asp.Net Mvc 4 single page application?

```
public class MyModel 
{ 
    [DisplayName("fancy name")]
    public int A { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this @LabelFor

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Name)
```

Comment: First, `m=>m.FirstOrDefault().Name` is not a supported expression by the helpers and second, how does this answer the question?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Ok so sorry I Update

Comment: SPA doesn't use razor to render the html page except the very few login/authorization related part.

Comment: I test and search i think u can see this articlehttp://architects.dzone.com/articles/single-page-app-knockoutjs-0